# c/c++ - How to write an array of boolean value into a text file?

Tags: c++, io

I have a very big array of boolean values, and I want to write it to a `.txt` file.

I tried `fwrite()` and when I use `cat` command to print the output `.txt` file, it print some strange symbols on the screen.

I want it to show as `0` and `1`. How to do that?

```
bool* tmp = new bool[size]; // tmp has actual values in it, this is just used to show what are tmp and size
FILE* f = fopen("result.txt", "wb");
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                fwrite(tmp, sizeof(bool), num_sample_per_point, f);
                fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, f); // insert new line
        }
        fclose(f);
```

Also, I've thought about converting those values to `int` values, but is that too costy because the size of the array is quite big.

Comment: C or C++? If it is C++, please use `std::ofstream` instead of `fwrite`.

Comment: Please post your erroneous code

Comment: @Rakete1111 I use cuda actually and it seems both c and c++ can be compiled, so I prefer the simpler one.

Comment: Write the "costly" code, get it working, then see how you can make it "cheaper".

Comment: if int is too big, use _char_ array that holds zeros and ones

Comment: What is `tmp`? What is `size`? What are the strange symbols? Is it all strange? Or just some of it?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: If you want an ascii text file, your tmp had better be char tmp[999] filled with ascii '0's and '1's. Or else, if tmp's filled with 0,1 bits, make an ascii char atmp[999] array, and a loop that fills it with ascii '0's and '1's, based on the corresponding 0,1 bits in tmp. Then fwrite atmp using sizeof(char).

Comment: Why write in binary if you want to read it as text?

Comment: The question's code edit shows this is not C code.

Comment: @doctorlove Well, the tmp array is actually an array returned from GPU, I use boolean type just to decrease the size of data that is transferred between CPU and GPU to save time. And now I have to save these binart numbers.

Comment: `... is that too costly ....` No, when writing to a file, there is (almost) nothing that you do in the CPU that is too costly. File operations are incredible slow compared to speed of executing "normal code". So don't worry about converting the `bool` values to other types - it will not impact performance much.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the binary representation of a type T to file will not give you a human readable text file (except for the type `char`). Writing a `bool` type with value true, could produce the binary pattern `00000001` and using `cat` on the file will **not** print the letter `1`.

If you want the file to contain letters with `0` for false and `1` for true, you have to convert the bool value first.

Keeping your code style, it could look like:

```
int main(void) {
  const int size = 3;
  bool tmp[size] = {false, true, false};
  FILE* f = fopen("result.txt", "w");
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    fwrite(tmp[i] ? "1" : "0", sizeof(char), 1, f);
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //     convert bool to letter
  }
  fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, f); // insert new line
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice: If you are writing c++ you should take a look at `std::ofstream`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save human readable data to a file, open it for text:

```
FILE* f = fopen("result.txt", "wt");
//                              ^-----
```

otherwise it's written as binary.
 You will then need to consider the specifics of what you write. If you want a 1 or 0 for a boolean, you need to write code for this.

Comment: Changing file mode will not turn everything into "readable data".

Comment: Agreed there is more to it than that, but this is one obvious change required for the posted code.